# Shadowsocks won't open. Unexpected Error. Windows 10. Pls advice

Tags: proxy

I am trying to use Shadowsocks. When I open it this error shows:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8OeR.png)

This is a somewhat fresh Windows 10 Pro install. Interesting thing is I have same Windows 10 image on virtual host and Shadowsocks works there. Identical install.

I wonder if just some updates need to be installed? Just there is limited speed and bandwidth at the location I am in now and if it's an update deal maybe someone could point to exact update or framework that I can install manually. Or possible other fixes. Thanks!

PS: Shadowsocks version 4.4.1.0

Comment: Looks to me like it cant load a .NET component. (Re)Install the latest (or compatible) .NET framework.

Comment: That or another update must have been it, thx.